# Matplotlib: can a colormap imply a different default normalization?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following color map:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, NoNorm

mycmap_dict = {
    'red': (
            (-2.0, 1.0, 1.0),
            (-1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
            ( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            ( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0),
            ( 2.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        ),

    'green': (
            (-1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
            ( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            ( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
            ( 2.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        ),

    'blue': (
            (-2.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            (-1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
            ( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            ( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        )
    }

my_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap('my', mycmap_dict)
plt.register_cmap(cmap=my_cmap)

my_norm = NoNorm()
```

Since the color map is based around data in the range [-2.0, 2.0] rather than [0.0, 1.0], using a default normalization doesn't make sense.  I would like to be able to say "use my_norm by default when using my_cmap" -- is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the short answer is: No.

For the best interpolability between your custom colormaps and normalisations, I'd strongly encourage you to stick to the rules:

- Norm takes data and converts to 0-1*
- Cmap takes floats in the range 0-1 and converts to RGBA values

* There is an exception to this rule - sometimes you want to *index* into a colormap, and so I believe there is a case where the norm returns bytes which are then used to access colors by index in the colormap.

Sorry the answer wasn't yes :-)